# jQuery check if value of input is in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check if the value of an input field is in the array but it doesn't seem to work.

This is what I have tried:

```
var postcode1 = [];
    for (var i = 21000; i < 21999; i++) {
        postcode1.push({ val: i, text: i });        
    }
    console.log(postcode1);

    $('#fw_form_field_146').blur(function() {
        var val = $("#fw_form_field_146").val();
        if( $.inArray(val, postcode1) > -1 ) {
            alert('test');
        }
    });
```

The array is outputting in console.log but the check doesn't work when i fill in the input field.

Comment: Your array contains objects, but you're checking if a string is there.  It won't ever be.

Answer (score 1):

Since *postcode1* it's an array which contains `val-text` values, you have to use `map` method by passing a `callback` provided function as argument.

Also, you need to use `Number` constructor because the `value` returned from `input` it's a `string` and your `given` array contains **primitive** `numbers`

```js
var postcode1 = [];
for (var i = 21000; i < 21999; i++) {
    postcode1.push({ val: i, text: i });        
}

$('#fw_form_field_146').blur(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if( $.inArray(Number(val), postcode1.map(({val}) => val)) !== -1 ) {
        alert('test');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fw_form_field_146"/>
```

Another approach it to use `includes` method.

```js
var postcode1 = [];
for (var i = 21000; i < 21999; i++) {
    postcode1.push({ val: i, text: i });        
}

$('#fw_form_field_146').blur(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(postcode1.map(({val})=> val).includes(Number(val))) {
        alert('test');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fw_form_field_146"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the var val is empty when i fill in the input field the value needs to change when i leave the input box how can I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using findIndex instead of inArray, which will allow you to have a more accurate search conditions. Like this:

```
 if (postcode1.findIndex((item) => item.val.toString() === val) > -1 ) {
            alert('test');
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead since you need to check on the objects in the array and not the array itself.

```
$('#fw_form_field_146').blur(function() {
  var val = $("#fw_form_field_146").val();
  if (postcode1.filter((e) => e.val == val).length > 0) {
    alert('test');
  }
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var postcode1 = [];
for (var i = 21000; i < 21999; i++) {
  postcode1.push({
    val: i,
    text: i
  });
}

$('#fw_form_field_146').blur(function() {
  var val = $("#fw_form_field_146").val();
  if (postcode1.filter((e) => e.val == val).length > 0) {
    alert('test');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fw_form_field_146" />
```